# How to Use Random or Suffle Data on MySQL using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, random, xampp, shuffle

Hello i have tables like this :

**Employee**

```
EmployeeID  EmployeeName 
1234        Suho    
1235        Kai    
1236        Baekhyun    
1237        Lay  
1238        D.O      
1239        Chen
1240        Chanyeol
1241        Xiumin
1242        Sehun
```

i used this source code to make random data :

```
<?php

mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "1234") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("Employee") or die(mysql_error());

$employees = mysql_query("select p.*
from (select (@c := CHAR(ASCII(@c) + 1)) as c, EmployeeName
      from Employee cross join
           (select @c := 'A') params
      order by EmployeeId
     ) p order by rand();") 
or die(mysql_error());  

$letters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
$position = 0;
$position2 = 0;
$toomany = '';

while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $employees )) {
    echo "<DIV>" . $toomany.substr($letters, $position, 1) . " = " . $row['EmployeeName'] . " </div>";
      $position ++;
    if($position > 25) {
        $position = 0;
        $position2 ++;
        if($position2 > 25) { echo "We need to rethink this idea."; break; }
        $toomany = substr($letters, $position2, 1);
    }
}

?>
```

After random the data, the result is like this :

```
A  = Sehun     
B  = Suho     
C  = Kai     
D  = D.O     
E  = Chen       
F  = Chanyeol
G  = Baekhyun
F  = Lay
H  = Xiumin
```

or like this :

```
A  = Kai     
B  = Suho     
C  = Sehun    
D  = D.O     
E  = Chen       
F  = Xiumin
G  = Lay
F  = Chanyeol
H  = Baekhyun
```

The problem is i want to random that data like this (From the database before, EmployeeID changed by alphabet sequentially):

```
A = Suho     
B = Kai    
C = Baekhyun    
D = Lay  
E = D.O      
F = Chen
G = Chanyeol
H = Xiumin
I = Sehun
```

into this one, the data have with the same value but with a different sequence (Only their potition change, not only their names were randomized) :

```
G = Chanyeol  
C = Baekhyun   
B = Kai  
D = Lay  
I = Sehun
E = D.O      
F = Chen
A = Suho
H = Xiumin
```

or like this :

```
I = Sehun
E = D.O  
C = Baekhyun
G = Chanyeol    
B = Kai 
H = Xiumin 
D = Lay        
F = Chen
A = Suho
```

May you know where is the problem? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why don't you shuffle in PHP? You can store the unshuffled results in an associative array, using the letter as KEY, and the name (Sehun, etc) as value. For a simple associative array shuffle, see first comment here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php

Comment: How is that supposed to work with more than 26 rows? I see you wrote support for that. For example only ABC in $letters, give an example of output with 7 rows.

Comment: Just a notice: Don't use `ORDER BY RAND()` on large datasets. They tend to get very slow very quick. Better to select a random range in php and randomize in php rather than let MySQL do it...

Answer (score 0):

Get all from the DB and keep it into a PHP Array, then apply one of the randomize PHP Functions. [Shuffle](http://php.net/manual/es/function.shuffle.php) changes the keys, so I saw [someone who posted a nice function](http://php.net/manual/es/function.shuffle.php#94697) in the PHP.net website which keeps the indexes:

```
<?php
    function shuffle_assoc(&$array) {
        $keys = array_keys($array);

        shuffle($keys);

        foreach($keys as $key) {
            $new[$key] = $array[$key];
        }

        $array = $new;

        return true;
    }
?>
```

Comment: i have tried this one too, but nohing happened you can check in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31282438/how-to-display-random-data-on-mysql-using-php/31282503?noredirect=1#comment50558903_31282503 thank you